# List all products with all options

Tags: commerce

We need to output a list of all products with all options. Example:

- 5 models of bicycles -- The Product
- Each model comes in three different wheel sizes (and wheel size option might vary by model) -- Wheel Size option type with specific options
- Each model might also have other options, such as with or without basket

So the list might be:

- Model A 26"
- Model A 26" with basket
- Model A 28"
- Model A 28" with basket
- Model A 30"
- Model A 30" with basket
- Model B 24"
- Model B 26"

and so forth.

I figured that I could create an Commerce Option view, then add a relationship to the product so that I could add the title/name field from Product to generate the list. But Relationship doesn't have an option to create a relationship to the Commerce Product.

In reality, there are something like 9,000 various options for the entire product line so a method of automating the list is important. After the view is successfully set up, we'll be exporting once and never used again. Any help is appreciated!